# How to join select two tables with condition on column sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, case

I have a table in sql server structured like this table1

```
----------------------------
| ID | year | code | value |
----------------------------
|  1 | 2019 |  41  |  33   |
|  1 | 2019 |  42  |  34   |
|  2 | 2019 |  42  |  35   |
|  2 | 2019 |  43  |  36   |
----------------------------
```

and this table2

```
---------------------
| ID | year | index |
---------------------
|  1 | 2019 |  15   |
|  2 | 2019 |  16   |
---------------------
```

and somehow I want to select join them and become like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID | year | index | value_code_41 | value_code_42 | value_code_43 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | 2019 |  15   |      33       |      34       |       0       |
|  2 | 2019 |  16   |       0       |      35       |      36       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I already try case like this but it return 0 in value_code_42 and value_code_43

```
select  b.*,
        case when a.value !=0 and kode=41 then a.value else 0 end as value_code_41,
        case when a.value !=0 and kode=42 then a.value else 0 end as value_code_42,
        case when a.value !=0 and kode=43 then a.value else 0 end as value_code_43
from table1 a, table2 b
where a.year=b.year and a.id=b.id
```

what is wrong with my select case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate to pivot the dataset:

```
select  
    b.id,
    b.year, 
    b.index,
    max(case when a.kode = 41 then a.value else 0 end) as value_code_41,
    max(case when a.kode = 42 then a.value else 0 end) as value_code_42,
    max(case when a.kode = 43 then a.value else 0 end) as value_code_43
from table1 a
inner join table2 b on a.year = b.year and a.id = b.id
group by b.id, b.year, b.index
```

Comment: okay thanks dude, sorry for the late reply, recently I got another project and I just got time to open stack overflow again